# Does having a land border with an AI player increase the risk that it will dislike me?

Tags: freeciv

Does an AI civilization's attitude depend on whether or not my civilization has a land border with the AI's civilization? I have noticed that the attitude of my immediate AI neighbors tend to deteriorate faster than that of other AI civilizations that are further away.